# fs.appendFileSync(path) call closes file handle in node.js?

Tags: node.js, fs

There are two apis
1)fs.appendFileSync(path) which takes in path of the file and
2)fs.appendFileSync(fd) which takes in file descriptor, the second one doesnt close the file handle which makes sense cause its borrowed from outside of the function, but what about the the first call? Since a fd is made internal to function does it closes it? No docs mentioned about the first overloaded api? Also of the fd is open internally how do i acquire to close it?

https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v16.x/api/fs.html#fsappendfilesyncpath-data-options

Comment: Sounds like a question for the node docs issue tracker? If the docs are unclear, get the docs fixed =)

Comment: Dude this question is to research my findings first, else everything on SO is a documentation bug or a bug for missing documentation on a given usecase ..

Comment: Sure, and no not at all, respectively - in this case, you have a question about the Node documentation that you couldn't solve _by reading the Node documentation_. Since Node's docs are open source, and only improve when folks like you run into problems and ask them to fix that. And asking for that on the docs issue tracker means that _everyone who uses Node_ benefits from those improvements: if the API docs already answer the question you have _about the API_ then that solves the problem at the point where it should be solved. Even if you keep this particular question open on SO too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the `lib/fs.js` code, `fs.appendFileSync()` **does close the file** when it is complete.

`if (!isUserFd) fs.closeSync(fd)` is called at the end of the process, closing the file if the `fd` wasn't passed in.

Here are the links to Node.JS 16.x code from the Node project on GitHub - I tried to match source version with the version docs you were looking at.

`function appendFileSync(path, data, options) {`
https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/b8a8c83dffea8422db003e9444d4526ebafbd36a/lib/fs.js#L2222

`function writeFileSync(path, data, options) {`
https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/b8a8c83dffea8422db003e9444d4526ebafbd36a/lib/fs.js#L2159

Hope that helps.